# Duplicating / Creating a copy of the original file

Tags: php

I have a file test.php in that i want to add a PHP script in such a way that whenever test.php is being exceuted/opened it should copy itself to a directory /copies/test.php
How do i do that ? and it would be better if i could rename it.

Comment: Are you trying to have backups of files, sort of like version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
<?php
  copy(__FILE__,dirname(__FILE__).'/copies/'.basename(__FILE__));
?>
```

Comment: Note, this'll copy it into copies/ which is a subdirectory of the current one. Not sure if that's what you wanted. If not, get rid of the `dirname(__FILE__)` bit and replace it with the full path to your directory.

Answer (score 1):

you want to copy all test.php php code or result from that code?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very zoomed-in solution to a problem that might be much easier to solve. Have you thought about sharing the problem as a whole? You never know...